# Mounting ISO9660 File System in Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, filesystems, openstack

I am booting Windows 2008 instances in an OpenStack environment. OpenStack can use a "[config drive](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/admin/content/config-drive.html)" to pass metadata information to the instances. This drive is formatted as a ISO9660 (or optionally VFAT) File System.

In our system we can't use HTTP metadata, so this "config drive" is really our only option.

Is there any way to mount this under Windows? Windows can see the disk, but only shows it as unallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [cloudbase-init](https://github.com/cloudbase/cloudbase-init), which claims to support config drive under Windows guests. I have never personally tried it, though, so can't vouch for whether it works or not.

Comment: It only supports config drive for Windows 2012 and up unfortunately.